# GUI Error while removing from the defaultListModel

Tags: java

I am getting error while removing data from the DefaultListModel actually problem is that the element which I am removing is selected in the valueChanged method so thats why remove button throws error i even try to add clearSelection method but nothing is working

```
class LoginPanel extends JPanel {
private final JTextArea area;
private final DefaultListModel<String>  defaultOrderList ;

 public LoginPanel() {

 defaultOrderList = new DefaultListModel<String>();

 orderList = new JList<String>(defaultOrderList);
        orderList.addListSelectionListener(new listHandler());
        orderList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        add(new JScrollPane(orderList));

  area = new JTextArea();
    area.setEditable(false);

 removeButton = new JButton("Remove part");

}

    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {



//when i click the remove button it shows the error

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   if(e.getSource()== removeButton){
                    totalPrice-=order.getParts().get(orderList.getSelectedIndex()).getPrice();

                    area.setText("");

                    order.removeComputerPart(orderList.getSelectedIndex());
                    defaultOrderList.removeElementAt(orderList.getSelectedIndex());



                }

}

  private class listHandler implements ListSelectionListener {

   if (e.getSource() == orderList) {



                area.setText(order.getParts().get(orderList.getSelectedIndex()).getID()+"\n"+"$"+order.getParts().get(orderList.getSelectedIndex()).getPrice()+"\n"+
                     checkCompatiblity(order.getParts().get(orderList.getSelectedIndex()))

  );

//here is where i get an error which i seen from the command prompt





            }

}

}
}



}
```

while checking the problem through command prompt i get an error out of bond

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 3
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:266)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:427)


    \\main class name is CSFrame so here it shows the error
    at LoginPanel$listHandler.valueChanged(CSFrame.java:472)



    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JList.fireSelectionValueChanged(JList.java:1804)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JList$ListSelectionHandler.valueChanged(JList.java:1818)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:224)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:204)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:251)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.removeIndexInterval(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:720)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI$Handler.intervalRemoved(BasicListUI.java:2793)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireIntervalRemoved(AbstractListModel.java:188)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultListModel.removeElementAt(DefaultListModel.java:334)
    at LoginPanel$ButtonHandler.actionPerformed(CSFrame.java:396)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6617)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6382)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2264)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4993)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2322)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4825)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4934)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4563)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4504)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4825)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: It would appear that `orderList.getSelectedIndex()` returns -1 (minus one). I may be able to help you debug your code if you post a [mcve]. Note that removing large parts of your code and posting what's left (blank lines included) does **not** constitute a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: In my `ListSelectionListener` implementations, I usually first call method [getValueIsAdjusting](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionEvent.html#getValueIsAdjusting()) and only do anything if that method returns false. Refer to [How to Write a List Selection Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html)